# Proof of why Randomization is Important In Experiments

Tags: sampling, random-variable

A simple example: I am interested in finding out the average height of student's at a university - but I only decide to measure the basketball team. Intuitively, I know this will result in a biased estimate. What is the mathematical proof that randomization is important in sampling/experimentation?

Comment: This does not seem to be the kind of assertion that is subject to a mathematical proof.  Your question therefore might be more productive if it were broadened into one asking about the kinds and nature of evidence that indicate randomization is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with a proof, but the general concept is known as [Sampling bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_bias).

Answer (score -3):

The keywords is "statistically significant": you have to prove the experimental results is valid, and reproducible as well. To be able to do it, you will need to repeat the experiments many many times to show that they are consistent (and that you don't get a contaminated sample - as opposed to representative sample). In your experiments, you will (and definitely will) have experimental error, at least at a constant of Planck's constant (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle). The goal is to measure the mean of the population that is an object of your interest. Statistics is very very important to validate your results.

Comment: The question was about "randomization",  a term that does not appear in the answer.